# "Query" vs. "Inquiry"

Tags: word-choice, differences, semantics

What is the difference between the words "inquiry" and "query?"  I tend to associate the latter with technology (e.g., search engine queries), but I'm not sure what the actual meaning is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> **inquiry** describes an act of asking for information or an official investigation
>
> **query** is simply a question, especially one addressed to an official or an organization. In writing or speaking it is used to question the accuracy of a following statement or to introduce a question.

[NOAD]

Comment: (+1) A good answer. Concise and accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Query is asking a simple question that does not require more than basic knowledge.
Inquiry is asking a question that requires further research or an investigation.